# Wavy arrow that starts big, ends small

Tags: arrows

I'd like to produce a wavy arrow, but I'd like the oscillations of the arrow to begin large at the tail and end small at the head.  Anybody know of a way of accomplishing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming TikZ is fine.  You can plot a function of the form sin(x)*exp(-x).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-latex,samples=200,domain=0:10] plot (\x,{2*sin(\x*3 r)*exp(-\x/4)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very cool, works perfect and is easily amended for size and shape!  Only part of this I don't quite understand is what the 'r' is doing there.  Something about radians?

Comment: @Addem Yes, the `sin` function assumes degrees by default, with the `r` you get radians.